# Modelo ER, como plantear la logíca correctamente?

Tags: mysql, sql

me gustaria saber cual es la forma correcta de plantear la logica a la hora de hacer el modelo entidad/relaccion. Por ejemplo, tengo dos tablas, una es la tabla "vacunas" y la otra "animales". 
Como planteo esto? por un lado tengo que, un animal puede tener 0/n vacunas, y una vacuna la pueden tener 0/n animales? Relaccion N/M?

Comment: En el modelo entidad-relación no se hace mención a tablas sino a *entidades*, *relaciones* y *atributos*. Lo que tu propones es un modelo lógico y no conceptual, es decir un modelo relacional. Sería de gran utilidad que conocieras los conceptos básicos para formular una buena pregunta y que la comunidad pueda apoyarte con tu duda.

Comment: Amigo, te recomiendo leas el tema de 'normalización', ahí saldrás de esa duda y podrás desarrollar bien tus próximos modelos.

Answer (score 3):

para esos casos se hace una tabla intermedia que relacione a las otras dos. Los registros de esta tabla te dice que vacunas corresponde a que animal y que animales tienen que vacuna.

Las relaciones `0-N` en ambos sentidos producen siempre una tabla intermedia que las relaciona.

Estás tablas intermedias contienen las claves primarias de las que relacionan y opcionalmente pueden contener otro dato, pero esto último sería lo menos común.

La ausencia de registros en esta tabla te dicen que:

- Si la vacuna no se encuentra, no hay animal que la reciba.
- Si el animal no se encuentra, no hay vacunas para ese animal.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, para la relación que planteas se crean tablas intermedias en donde los registros primarios de cada tabla principal se relacionan en la nueva tabla.

Para este caso la tabla intermedia representaría que mascota tiene "X" vacuna y que serie de "X" vacuna fue colocada a tal mascota. Para mayor precisión en esa tabla intermedia puede estar puesta la fecha de puesta de vacuna.

Espero haberte ayudado, no dudes en consultar.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo con los dos comentarios de arriba, es decir, debes definir que tabla será la principal, en este caso (Según mi criterio) es la tabla de animales, y posterior la de vacunas. Bien, ¿como las uno? Tomando en cuenta los IDs ejemplo:

Tabla de animales: id_animal, animal_nombre, animal_edad, animal_color, (entre_otros)

Tabla de vacunas: id_vacuna, nombre_vacuna, periodo de vacuna, (entre_otros)

Tabla de vacunas aplicadas: id_vacuna_aplicada, vacuna, animal, fecha, nombre_dueno, (entre_otros).

Si, pueden haber muchas más tablas para llenar la información pero en este caso si debe haber una tabla intermediaría y esa sería la manera relacional. **NO puedes ligar directamente la tabla animales con la de vacunas saber fechas o vacunas que tiene puesto una mascota o animal, si lo haces estarías trabajando de una pésima manera que hablaría mal de tu trabajo**

Comment: En StakOverflow, no existe la _respuesta_ de _arriba_ (si el comentario, pero supongo que tu te refieres a otras respuestas). Las respuestas se pueden ordenar de acuerdo a la actividad, a la antigüedad o al número de votos. Si en tu respuesta haces referencia a otras respuestas, es mejor que incluyas un vínculo a cada una.

Answer (score 0):

Pues, tal y como planteas en el texto, lo estás haciendo correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Únicamente tienes que tener en cuenta que en el modelo ER de Chen no puedes vincular directamente dos entidades (nombres), sino que debes utilizar una relación (verbo) que le dé sentido a la semántica que defines. Cuando pases esta estructura al modelo relacional serán todo tablas (relaciones) y, cuando registres datos, verás cómo todo cobra sentido.

Es cierto que, cuando la cardinalidad es 1, puedes propagar uno de los atributos de la relación a la entidad que corresponda y puedes prescindir de la tabla intermedia (relación en el modelo relacional) pero, la relación (del modelo ER), no deja de existir y debes reflejarla siempre en tu esquema. Es decir, no es que a veces necesites una tabla intermedia, sino que, sólo en ciertos casos, puedes propagar sus campos a otras tablas.